# Custom installation file for Windows program

Tags: windows, installation, executable

I need to create an installation file for Windows in such a way that the setup:

1. Registers the .exe at startup so it launches everytime machine is booted
2. Runs the .exe and opens a webpage upon completing installation .

Could anyone please give me some tips on how I could do this?

Comment: are you looking to startup when a user logs in or as a service when the machine startups up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to look into using [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/index.html) to create the installer.

For requirement #1, you could put a shortcut into the startup folder, as discussed [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Howto-add-shortcut-to-startup-menu-td709690.html).

For requirement #2, you can execute a [ShellExecute CustomAction](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/shellexec.htm) to open the URL, and I believe, run the application.

Answer (score 1):

Any installer can do all of the above. A good free one is [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php); make sure you also download a GUI script creation tool like [ISTool](http://www.istool.org/) or [InnoIDE](http://www.innoide.org/) (also free). I've used ISTool, but not InnoIDE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in installers such as Inno Setup, Windows Installer, Wise, InstallShield, etc. The real problem is how to make a program runs in every start-up of Windows. There are many choices to do that. One way is to put your EXE program path in the following registry key:

```
  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
      or
  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
```

But there many other locations would do. It depends on what kind of program you had, in which start-up stage you want the program starts, and in what context the program will be run (local machine or current user). Please read the following article in MSDN

[Understand and Control Startup Apps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851671.aspx)

So, after you choose an appropriate location for your need, you choose which Installer you are going to use to implement it. If you're a Delphi/Pascal programmer, Inno Setup is made for you; If you like PHP language, maybe NSIS is the right choice; and so on.

On Windows Vista and later, you must concern the UAC issue. If you use Inno Setup, be sure to include the following statement in `[Setup]` section

```
  PrivilegesRequired=admin
```

On Windows Vista and later, if you want to suppress the notification that some *uncertified* autostarting programs has been blocked by Windows, you should use Task Scheduler to set your program runs automatically at Windows start-up. You could execute Task Scheduler by running `Schtasks.exe` from your installation program. See the [command line options for Task Scheduler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx) and [its description](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28WS.10%29.aspx).